# Syntax for ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with positional placeholders

Tags: php, mysql

This is `REPLACE` syntax

```
$sql = "REPLACE INTO 2_1_journal (Number,RecordDay, RecordMonth) VALUES ";
$insertQuery = array();
$insertData = array();
foreach ($_POST['row_id'] as $i => $row_id) {
$insertQuery[] = '(?, ?, ?)';
$insertData[] = $row_id;
$insertData[] = $_POST['date_day'][$i];
$insertData[] = $_POST['date_month'][$i];
}
if (!empty($insertQuery)) {
$sql .= implode(', ', $insertQuery);
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($insertData);
}
```

However read that instead of `REPLACE` better use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Trying to change like this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 2_1_journal (Number,RecordDay, RecordMonth) VALUES ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (RecordDay, RecordMonth) ";
$insertQuery = array();
$insertData = array();
foreach ($_POST['row_id'] as $i => $row_id) {
$insertQuery[] = '(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
$insertData[] = $row_id;
$insertData[] = $_POST['date_day'][$i];
$insertData[] = $_POST['date_month'][$i];
$insertData[] = $_POST['date_day'][$i];
$insertData[] = $_POST['date_month'][$i];
}
if (!empty($insertQuery)) {
$sql .= implode(', ', $insertQuery);
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($insertData);
}
```

But does not work (neither inserts nor updates)

What is incorrect?

If downvote, please write in comments why (for me to avoid write things that cause downvote)

**Update**

Changed code to this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 2_1_journal (Number, RecordDay) VALUES ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE RecordDay";
$insertQuery = array();
$insertData = array();
foreach ($_POST['row_id'] as $i => $row_id) {
$insertQuery[] = '(?, ?)';
$insertData[] = $row_id;
$insertData[] = $_POST['date_day'][$i];
}
```

get SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE RecordDay('21', ''), ('22', '')' at line 1

Changed to this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 2_1_journal (Number, RecordDay) VALUES ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE RecordDay=VALUES(Number)";
$insertQuery = array();
$insertData = array();
foreach ($_POST['row_id'] as $i => $row_id) {
$insertQuery[] = '(?, ?)';
$insertData[] = $row_id;
$insertData[] = $_POST['date_day'][$i];
```

get SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE RecordDay=VALUES(Number)('21', ''), ('22', '')' at line 1

Changed code to this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 2_1_journal (Number, RecordDay) VALUES ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE RecordMonth=?";
$insertQuery = array();
$insertData = array();
foreach ($_POST['row_id'] as $i => $row_id) {
$insertQuery[] = '(?, ?, ?)';
$insertData[] = $row_id;
$insertData[] = $_POST['date_day'][$i];
$insertData[] = $_POST['date_month'][$i];
```

get SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Can I make conclusion that last example is valid SQL syntax. But why error? Number, RecordDay, RecordMonth=? and `$insertQuery[] = '(?, ?, ?)';` 3 variables and 3 tokens? Or I am wrong?

If `$insertQuery[] = '(?, ?)';` the same 
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Please, help. I am stuck.... no idea

**Working code!!!**

```
try {
$sql = "INSERT INTO 2_1_journal (Number, RecordDay) VALUES ";
$insertQuery = array();
$insertData = array();
foreach ($_POST['row_id'] as $i => $row_id) {
$insertQuery[] = '(?, ?)';
$insertData[] = $row_id;
$insertData[] = $_POST['date_day'][$i];
}
if (!empty($insertQuery)) {
$sql .= implode(', ', $insertQuery) . 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE RecordDay = VALUES(RecordDay);';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($insertData);
}
}
catch (PDOException $e){
echo "DataBase Error: " .$e->getMessage() .'<br>';
}
catch (Exception $e) {
echo "General Error: ".$e->getMessage() .'<br>';
}
```

Your comments, please. And see location of `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`!!!

Comment: Have you checked what your final query looks like before you put it in `prepare`? That simply doesn't add up to any sort of valid SQL query. And a reason for a downvote would be that you should experiment a lot more on your own, this is just about concatenating strings in the right order.

Comment: do you have any error message received? if so, what was it?

Comment: And your Query is very prone to sql injections.. Put some of your time to make it a bit secure at least for novices or computer jeeks

Comment: @ deceze Query inserts in mysql the same values that are entered in input form
@ JW No error message
@ScoRpion This is PDO
@ deceze query inserts in mysql the same values that are entered in input form

Comment: `var_dump($sql)` right before `prepare()`. Look at it, it's not valid.

Comment: @ deceze With print_r($sql); I get REPLACE INTO 2_1_journal (Number,RecordDay, RecordMonth) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?). What is invalid here....

Comment: var_dump($sql) is string(84) "REPLACE INTO 2_1_journal (Number,RecordDay, RecordMonth) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?)"

Comment: *That* is fine. The `ON DUPLICATE` version of it is invalid!

Comment: ok. will continue experiment `ON DUPLICATE`. I simply do not know syntax and can not find examples (tutorials) with positional placeholders. Actually I experimented for ~ 2 hours before asked here...

Comment: Changed code to `$sql = "INSERT INTO 2_1_journal (Number,RecordDay, RecordMonth) VALUES ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (Number,RecordDay, RecordMonth) ";` and got `string(139) "INSERT INTO 2_1_journal (Number,RecordDay, RecordMonth) VALUES ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (Number,RecordDay, RecordMonth) (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?)" `

Comment: The correct SQL syntax should be `INSERT INTO <table> VALUES (?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a=a+1`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: You mean `a` is mysql column name? In my case `RecordDay=RecordDay+1`. Get syntax error...

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use code to build SQL statement, add a line:

```
echo $sql;
```

just before executing the statement. This way you can see what you are actually executing.

You can then cut & paste the SQL statement directly into the database, and see what happens.

Also -- to prevent SQL injection, add

```
$row_id = mysql_real_escape_string($POST['row_id']);
$date_day = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date_day']);
$date_month = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date_month']);
```

to the beginning of your code, and then use $row_id instead of $POST['row_id'] in the rest of the code. And $date_day instead of $_POST['date_day'], and $date_month instead of $_POST['date_month'], etc -- do that for all your POST and GET variables.

Check this:
http://xkcd.com/327/